# How To Optimize This Objective-C Code

Tags: objective-c

I am teaching myself Objective-C and wrote this short little code to practice.

It works fine, but I don't think this is the right way to code with object-oriented programming.

How can I change the code so that I have a separate className.h file.  The interface, implementation, and main should all be separate instead of jammed in one code.  Any suggestions? Thanks

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 int courses, x;
 float grade, y;

 NSLog(@"Welcome to GPA Calculator \n How many courses are you taking?");
    scanf("%i",&courses);
 NSLog(@"You are taking %i courses", courses);

 while (x<courses) {
  NSLog(@"Please enter your grade for that course using number scale");
  scanf("%f",&grade);
  y=y+grade;
  x++;
    }
 NSLog(@"Your GPA is %f",y/courses);

 [pool drain];
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you abstract this little bit of code to objects, you're far from optimizing it.

Comment: note too that you never initialize x (so it's impossible to tell how long your first loop will run, if at all).   Also, you're assuming that all classes have an equal weight, which is seldom true as some will be 3 credits, some will be 4 credits, and others may be as little as 1 credit.  My point being, make sure you're ready to improve before you start improving (if it doesn't work, making it more complex won't help)

Comment: what do you mean by initializing x?  when I run the code, the loop works correctly meaning it runs the same number of times as the number of courses.  maybe I just got lucky?

Comment: "just got lucky" indeed. "initializing x" means that you need to set it to an initial value (zero, in this case) before you start using it. The test `while (x<courses)` assumes that "x" starts at zero, but you have not set it to zero, so you're lucky that chunk of memory happened to be zero, so it appears to "work correctly".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of refactoring code into classes and modules is to improve readability and maintainability. A trivial program like this would be made substantially *less* readable by such a refactoring, so it is difficult to offer meaningful advice on how it should be split up. The best answer I can offer is that it shouldn't.

Tackle some bigger projects, and then you can learn the use of modularisation techniques in their proper context.

> "Any intelligent fool can make things bigger, more complex, and more violent. It takes a touch of genius -- and a lot of courage -- to move in the opposite direction."
>     — Albert Einstein

Comment: Ok that makes perfect sense.  I guess ill check back when I have a program that is more complex.

Comment: Do you know of any websites that offer tutorials of some bigger projects that I can follow along with to learn?

Comment: @Faisal - first be sure that you understand how to code in the language that you have chosen.  Your questions above show that you don't understand much of the basics of Obj-C and this is going to cause great troubles in the future.